# Get absolute path of a property file

Tags: java, path

My Java EE application includes many sub-projects, which should use a single one configuration file to connect to the database. I intend to write a Java class and make it an independent jar to read the database connection parameters from `datasource.xml`, which will be put on the path of the independent jar.

The questions I want to ask:

1. How to dynamic get the absolute path of the `datasource.xml`?
2. Can the solution of the first question work in all operating systems like UNIX, etc?

Answer (score 2):

The first subject you have to deal with is where you store that file.

According to your question, you are going to be storing the file somewhere on the file system, externally to the actual application package. Therefore, you absolutely *must* know where the file is really located on the file system in order to access it; you can't conclude it in advance, unless you use environment variables that will instruct your code where the file is located.

A better approach is to package your XML file with the JAR. Then, you need not worry about absolute paths anymore. Simply use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource()`, providing the package-style path to the resource and you'll get a reference to it wherever it may be found.

If you can't package your file along with the JAR, you might be able to store it in a directory on the file system and add that directory to your server's classpath lookup sequence; some application servers support that. Then, you can still use the classloader to look up the resource, without requiring to know its absolute location.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Converting a relative path to absolute during runtime.. I guess that should work on all enviroments...

```
File a = new File("/some/abs/path");
File parentFolder = new File(a.getParent());
File b = new File(parentFolder, "../some/relative/path");
String absolute = b.getCanonicalPath(); // may throw IOException
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Environment Variables

```
String path = System.getEnv("MYVARIABLE");
File datasource = path + "/datasource.xml";
```

Or read in the location from a properties file available in a constant location

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try {
    props.load("MyFixed.properties");
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // Can do better
}
String path = props.getProperty("datasource.path");
File datasource = path + "/datasource.xml";
```

Or pass in a VM argument when starting the Jar with -D

```
String path = System.getProperty("datasource.path");
File datasource = path + "/datasource.xml";
```

and call with

```
java -jar -Ddatasource.path=/my/path/to/datasource.xml my.jar
```